# Orthogonality of odd dimensional unipotent matrices

Tags: gr.group-theory

Consider the orthogonal group $O(2l+1)$ ($l \geq 1$), is there an matrix in $O(2l+1)$ with its minimal polynomial being $(x-1)^{2l+1}$?

A similar question has been asked for the $O(2l)$ (this link : [Minimal polynomial of unipotents in orthogonal group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209427/minimal-polynomial-of-unipotents-in-orthogonal-group)) . So I am asking now for the $2l+1$ case.

Comment: The matrix then has only eigenvalue 1 and therefore it must be the identity matrix which has minimal polynomial x-1. Hence only for l=0 there exists such a matrix. In the link you provided they consider the split-orthogonal group which makes the problem probably more difficult.

Comment: I've edited it to $l \geq 1$, my question is for $O(3)$, $O(5)$ etc.

Comment: Then the answer is no by the explanation I gave.

Comment: The question remains if you consider the standard orthogonal group, i.e. all matrices with A^TA=I or some kind of split orthogonal group.

Comment: It will be easier to say something if you explain what you mean by $0(m)$.

Comment: @user100927 At least in the case of a finite field $K$, for the split orthogonal case $O_{2l}(K)$, there is no regular unipotent matrix in $O_{2l}(K)$, which has $J_{2l}$ as its Jordan form, since even sized Jordan blocks must have even multiplicity. See Page #38 of this paper: https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S1446788700027622 
So that's something I know in the split case. Hence it's the odd sized case, that's troubling.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean $\mathrm{O}_{2l+1}(K)$ ($K$ algebraically closed of char ≠ 2): any member of the regular unipotent class in $\mathrm{SO}_{2l+1}(K)$ has Jordan form $J_{2l+1}$, hence the desired minimal polynomial: see e.g. [Liebeck–Seitz](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2883501), [p. 57](https://books.google.com/books?id=Th-CAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA57&dq=%22First+we+discuss+the+regular+unipotent+class%22).

Comment: In the above, if we replace $K$ by a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ (of char $\neq$ 2). What happens then?

Comment: @UdayBhaskar: Same result, actually all of the unipotent classes will have a representative that is a matrix with entries in $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen That sounds right, and seems to be in Huppert ([1980](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=595627), Satz 3.2d) for any field of char ≠ 2. (In the finite case, signature automatically [$(l+1,l)$ or $(l,l+1)$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group_for_a_symmetric_bilinear_form#Over_finite_fields).)